# Can 数々 be read as【しばしば】?

Tags: multiple-readings, reduplication

Can 数々 be either 【かずかず】or 【しばしば】?

The websites j-talk.com and jisho.org both analyze the reading of the following sentence similarly:

パンデミック発生後【はっせいご】、ニューヨーク市内【しない】でもアジア人【じん】に対【たい】するヘイトクライムが数々【かずかず】報告【ほうこく】されてきた

*Since the outbreak of the pandemic, there have been numerous reports of hate crimes against Asians in New York City.* (translation by deepl.com)

https://webronza.asahi.com/national/articles/2021101000005.html?iref=comtop_Opinion_06

However, the following reading is also listed in jisho.org and Jim Breen's wwwjdic:

数々 【しばしば】*often; again and again; frequently; repeatedly*

However, there is only the 【かずかず】reading here:

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/数数/#jn-40989](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%95%B0%E6%95%B0/#jn-40989)

Can 数々 be read as 【しばしば】?

Comment: I have no personal knowledge but according to this dictionary one is a noun and the other is an adverb (you may need to scroll down a bit); https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%95%B0%E3%80%85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can compare several dictionaries [here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%B0).

For example, 精選版　日本国語大辞典 has

> しば‐しば【屡・屡屡・数・数数】
>
> 〔副〕 （副詞「しば（屡）」を重ねたもの） たびたび。しきりに。幾度も。何回となく。

So apparently even 数 alone can be used for しばしば.

I think using 数々 for しばしば is rather rare, most of the time hiragana is used. I have seen 屡/屡々 in older novels, but never 数々.

Comment: Thank you! I am self-taught and don't have a native speaker around to consult, so I am grateful for being able to profit from other stack exchange participants' experience with the language!